Matplotlib Assertion Error when plotting in Jupyter Lab Notebook
UPDATE (2024/09/21): I have changed pd.DataFrame.boxplot for pd.DataFrame.plot.box functions and restarted the Jupyter server. Now, it works repeatedly. No issues like before arise.
(I believe there is still a bug here, but I do not require any more help with this issue.)

I am getting this error when running pandas plotting commands inside jupyter lab.
Does anyone know what the issue is?
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 a2_data.boxplot(column=['MinTemp', 'MaxTemp', 'Rainfall', 'Evaporation', 'WindGustSpeed', 'WindSpeed9am', 'WindSpeed3pm', 'Humidity9am', 'Humidity3pm', 'Temp9am','Temp3pm'],rot=90);

File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py:533, in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, backend, **kwargs)
    516 @Substitution(data="", backend=_backend_doc)
    517 @Appender(_boxplot_doc)
    518 def boxplot_frame(
   (...)
    530     **kwargs,
    531 ):
    532     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 533     return plot_backend.boxplot_frame(
    534         self,
    535         column=column,
    536         by=by,
    537         ax=ax,
    538         fontsize=fontsize,
    539         rot=rot,
    540         grid=grid,
    541         figsize=figsize,
    542         layout=layout,
    543         return_type=return_type,
    544         **kwargs,
    545     )

File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py:492, in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    477 def boxplot_frame(
    478     self,
    479     column=None,
   (...)
    488     **kwds,
    489 ):
    490     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
--> 492     ax = boxplot(
    493         self,
    494         column=column,
    495         by=by,
    496         ax=ax,
    497         fontsize=fontsize,
    498         grid=grid,
    499         rot=rot,
    500         figsize=figsize,
    501         layout=layout,
    502         return_type=return_type,
    503         **kwds,
    504     )
    505     plt.draw_if_interactive()
    506     return ax

File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py:471, in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    468     else:
    469         data = data[columns]
--> 471     result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax, **kwds)
    472     ax.grid(grid)
    474 return result

File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py:414, in boxplot.<locals>.plot_group(keys, values, ax, **kwds)
    411     ax.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=fontsize)
    413 # GH 45465: x/y are flipped when "vert" changes
--> 414 _set_ticklabels(
    415     ax=ax, labels=keys, is_vertical=kwds.get("vert", True), rotation=rot
    416 )
    417 maybe_color_bp(bp, color_tup=colors, **kwds)
    419 # Return axes in multiplot case, maybe revisit later # 985

File C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py:57, in _set_ticklabels(ax, labels, is_vertical, **kwargs)
     55 if len(ticks) != len(labels):
     56     i, remainder = divmod(len(ticks), len(labels))
---> 57     assert remainder == 0, remainder
     58     labels *= i
     59 if is_vertical:

AssertionError: 3

I have restarted the kernel many times, my pc and also changed the backend config to use qt5agg to no avail. (Correction: yeah changed this back to inline cause qt5agg just spits them out as separate windows) This was all working fine before.
I expect the plots to produce inline, one after each code block i have. Other pandas functions work fine, its just the plotting specifically matplotlib.
Here is a code snippet in order of execution of the code blocks.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a2_data = pd.read_csv("13545429.csv")
a2_data.sample(10)

a2_data.boxplot(column=['MinTemp', 'MaxTemp', 'Rainfall', 'Evaporation', 'WindGustSpeed', 'WindSpeed9am', 'WindSpeed3pm', 'Humidity9am', 'Humidity3pm', 'Temp9am', 'Temp3pm'],rot=90);

Thats all.
Changing the command to a single column results in a blank output
a2_data.boxplot(column='Pressure9am')
outputs
<Axes: >
Here is the output of pd.show_versions() too if that helps.
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit                : d9cdd2ee5a58015ef6f4d15c7226110c9aab8140
python                : 3.12.1.final.0
python-bits           : 64
OS                    : Windows
OS-release            : 11
Version               : 10.0.22631
machine               : AMD64
processor             : AMD64 Family 25 Model 80 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
byteorder             : little
LC_ALL                : None
LANG                  : None
LOCALE                : English_Australia.1252

pandas                : 2.2.2
numpy                 : 2.0.1
pytz                  : 2024.1
dateutil              : 2.9.0.post0
setuptools            : 69.0.3
pip                   : 24.2
Cython                : None
pytest                : None
hypothesis            : None
sphinx                : None
blosc                 : None
feather               : None
xlsxwriter            : None
lxml.etree            : None
html5lib              : None
pymysql               : None
psycopg2              : None
jinja2                : 3.1.4
IPython               : 8.26.0
pandas_datareader     : None
adbc-driver-postgresql: None
adbc-driver-sqlite    : None
bs4                   : 4.12.3
bottleneck            : None
dataframe-api-compat  : None
fastparquet           : None
fsspec                : None
gcsfs                 : None
matplotlib            : 3.9.2
numba                 : None
numexpr               : None
odfpy                 : None
openpyxl              : None
pandas_gbq            : None
pyarrow               : None
pyreadstat            : None
python-calamine       : None
pyxlsb                : None
s3fs                  : None
scipy                 : None
sqlalchemy            : None
tables                : None
tabulate              : None
xarray                : None
xlrd                  : 2.0.1
zstandard             : None
tzdata                : 2024.1
qtpy                  : None
pyqt5                 : None


You definitely don't want qt5agg if you are running in JupyterLab. My guess is that you just have a mismatch in versions of Pandas and Matplotlib. You often need to keep them matching and if you use packages written or edited at vastly different times you can sometimes uncover incompatibilities. You should be providing code text and not just an error traceback. I'll need to look into it more later.

Do you have a shareable, minimal reproducible example that does the same thing? You only share the error traceback here and it isn't providing much detail to go on except it has to do with the ticks along the axis. So far my searches of issues in the Pandas repo aren't revealing anything related to that. Do the examples here all work for you?

@Wayne, None of the examples Pandas give work. I have also updated this post to add the length of the code that produces this result as you asked in your first comment. Regarding versions, no change was made between when it was working and when it broke. The only thing I can recall doing was installing Pandoc or letting my laptop go to sleep. However, I've just loaded up the file on my desktop PC using its installed versions, and it has become broken there, too.

Also just opened a new notebook on the same desktop PC and the pandas examples work fine.

I lost the thread there with your last comment saying the examples work fine. So does that mean it is something to do with your dataframe?

Possibly, but I don't see how my data frame is causing the issues if it used to work fine before.
My last comment noted that I created a fresh notebook on my desktop PC (the same pc that is having problems with the plotting), and I copied the pandas plotting examples into the new notebook, and they work fine. @Wayne

Update: I have changed pd.Dataframe.boxplot for pd.Dataframe.plot.box functions and restarted the jupyter server now it works repeatedly. No issues like before arise.

So if the issue is solved, could you add an 'UPDATE' section to the end of the question and say restarting things fixed it all? (Unless I misunderstand?)
